# Update query make record empty from MySQL in Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rest, codeigniter, image-uploading

I am trying to update records(first_name,last_name) from MySQL using Codeigniter
but if I do not update first_name OR last_name then record become empty from MySQL,
I want existing record should not be removed/deleted,how can I do this? here is my code

```
$add_data['user_id'] = ($this->input->post('user_id') && !empty($this->input->post('user_id'))) ? $this->input->post('user_id') : NULL;     
$add_data['first_name'] = ($this->input->post('first_name') && !empty($this->input->post('first_name'))) ? $this->input->post('first_name') : NULL;     
$add_data['last_name'] = ($this->input->post('last_name') && !empty($this->input->post('last_name'))) ? $this->input->post('last_name') : NULL;     
$data = array(
        'first_name'=>$add_data['first_name'],
        'last_name'=>$add_data['last_name'],
        );  
$this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
$query=$this->db->update('users', $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is snippet:

```
  $saveArr = [];
  if(!empty($this->input->post('first_name')){
       $saveArr['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
  }
  if(!empty($this->input->post('last_name')){
       $saveArr['last_name'] = $this->input->post('last_name');
  }
  $this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
  $query=$this->db->update('users',  $saveArr);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: and what about in image case ? if i not want to update my image then ?

Comment: another condition `if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {  .......   }`